# Why is my grammar being mutated?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I have a grammar:

```
#S(GRAMMAR

:START '

:SYMBOLS (i ) ( F * T + E)

:NONTS (F T E')

:PRODUCTIONS (#S(PRODUCTION :NONT ' :SENTENTIAL (@ E))
              #S(PRODUCTION :NONT E :SENTENTIAL (@ E + T))
              #S(PRODUCTION :NONT E :SENTENTIAL (@ T))
              #S(PRODUCTION :NONT T :SENTENTIAL (@ T * F))
              #S(PRODUCTION :NONT T :SENTENTIAL (@ F))
              #S(PRODUCTION :NONT F :SENTENTIAL (@ ( E )))
              #S(PRODUCTION :NONT F :SENTENTIAL (@ i))))
```

And this function:

```
(defun mgoto (s sym)
  (princ "Computing GOTO on: ")
  (princ sym)
  (princ #\Newline)
  (let ((result '())
        (st (copy-State s)))
    (map '()
         #'(lambda (x)
             (let ((dot (position sym (Production-sentential x))))
               (when (not (null dot))
                 (setq dot (1- dot))
                 (when (and (>= dot 0)
                            (char= #\@
                                   (nth dot (Production-sentential x))))
                   (let ((copy (copy-Production x)))
                     (rotatef (nth dot      (Production-sentential copy))
                              (nth (1+ dot) (Production-sentential copy)))
                     (format t "~A~%~%" copy)
                     (push copy result))))))
         (State-productions st))
    (make-state :name (list 'I (incf *COUNT*)) :productions result)))
```

which takes a state and a grammar symbol. The initial state looks like:

```
#S(STATE
    :NAME (I 0) 
    :PRODUCTIONS (#S(PRODUCTION :NONT ' :SENTENTIAL (@ E))
                  #S(PRODUCTION :NONT E :SENTENTIAL (@ T))
                  #S(PRODUCTION :NONT E :SENTENTIAL (@ E + T))
                  #S(PRODUCTION :NONT T :SENTENTIAL (@ F))
                  #S(PRODUCTION :NONT T :SENTENTIAL (@ T * F))
                  #S(PRODUCTION :NONT F :SENTENTIAL (@ I))
                  #S(PRODUCTION :NONT F :SENTENTIAL (@ ( E )))))
```

and is generated from:

```
(defun closure (g-prod gr)
  (let ((j (list (copy-Production (first g-prod))))
        (len0 0)
        (grammar gr))
    (loop do
          (setq len0 (length j))
          (map '()
               #'(lambda (jprod)
                   (map '()
                        #'(lambda (prod2)
                            (if (not (member prod2 j :test 'tree-equal))
                                (setq j (append j (list prod2)))))
                        (get-productions
                         (1+ (position #\@ (Production-sentential jprod)))
                         (Production-sentential jprod) grammar)))
               j)
          until (= (length j) len0))
    (list (make-State :name (list 'I (incf *COUNT*)) :productions j))))
```

`mgoto` on `alpha` will swap `@` with `alpha` for each production in state iff `@` is immediately before `alpha`. When I perform this operation on the state structure, the production in the original grammar also changes to reflect the changes I made them in mgoto.

I have tried to copy my structures as much as possible in order to leave the original grammar intact, but despite this, my grammar is always being modified when I compute the goto.

**Note:** In `closure`, the `gr` argument is passed in from a call to

```
(copy-Grammar)
```

**Reference:** I am computing the LR(0) set of items for a bottom-up parser:
http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~kulkarni/teaching/EECS665/assignments/LR0Items/output.txt

Do you have any suggestions for what I'm doing incorrectly?

**EDIT:**

The call to rotatef in mgoto I suspect is the problem.
Test case:

```
(rotatef (nth 0 (Production-Sentential (first (State-Productions any-state)))
         (nth 1 (Production-Sentential (first (State-Productions any-state))))
```

When I printed the original grammar and the modified state, both structures were modified.

Is there a way to make `rotatef` only modify the state structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your `copy-production` does only a shallow copy, i. e. it copies the top-level structure of a `production`, but the `sentential`s inside are copied as references.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case, but if you do

`(setf (Production-Sentential (first (State-Productions any-state)))
       (push #\r (Production-Sentential (first (State-Productions any-state))))` 

Then only the state is modified and the grammar is left alone

Comment: I ended up taking your advice and implemented my own deep copy